# Eloquent query - one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Guys I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to find the name of the user that answers a certain question:

```
$users = User::with('answers')->where('question_id', $request->question_id)->get();
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work.It seems like he is trying to find the `question_id` from the User and not from the Answer.

**Answer Model**

```
Class Answer extends Model{
  public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
Class User extends Authenticatable{
public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need a bit more details. What is the connection between the user and the question? You surely do need to select from the table question, as it seems to me.

Comment: well if you are familiar with Eloquent, their relationship is User has many Answers, and Answer belongs to User

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need, [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

```
$users = User::with(['answers' => function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('question_id', $request->question_id)
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you asked for but maybe what you need:

```php
$answers = Answer::with('user')->where('question_id', $request->question_id)->get();
```